# Stored procedure for often-used query?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm writing a long QC script for checking data after import. After every step in the script, I'd like to write the result to an auditlog:

```
insert into [AUDIT_LOG] (finished, query, result) 
values (getdate(), 'Create QC table', 'Table Created');
```

I am using this query over 100x throughout the script. Is there a way to shorten this? Something like

```
audit_log('Create QC table', 'Table Created');
```

So a custom function that would look like (pseudo)

```
begin function audit_log(@query, @result)
  insert into [AUDIT_LOG] (finished, query, result) 
  values (getdate(), @query, @result);
end
```

Is this what stored procedures are meant for? (I'm a beginner trying to figure some stuff out)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your idea is right, and you code is close-ish.

```
create proc dbo.make_audit_log(@query varchar(100), @result varchar(100)) as
    insert into [AUDIT_LOG] (finished, query, result) 
       values (getdate(), @query, @result);
go
```

Then to use this

```
exec dbo.make_audit_log 'your query', 'your result'.
```

**Edit**: Good spot by @IvanGerasimenko - the table and the SP will have to have different names, code above tweaked accordingly.

Comment: SP and table name could not be the same http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/48051/can-i-give-the-same-name-to-a-table-and-a-stored-procedure. Unless they are in two different schemas.

Comment: Pr0no, function is not an option, because you can not use INSERT inside a function for regular tables, except for local table variables.

Comment: I'm using `if object_id('make_audit_log', 'U') is not null drop procedure make audit_log go` and I get returned `Command(s) completed successfully.` However, if I then run the `create procedure` statement, I get returned `There is already an object named 'make_audit_log' in the database.` Why was it not deleted, even though I get no error returned?

create procedure dbo.audit_log (
   @query varchar(100)
 , @result varchar(100) 
) as
 insert into [CA131RB01_QC] (finished, query, result) 
 values (getdate(), @query, @result)
go

Comment: Always use the schema part of object names, dbo.make_audit_log for example.

Answer (score 2):

Declare it as a stored procedure and place the call to it inside your script:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SaveAuditLog]
    @query NVARCHAR(255)
    ,@result NVARCHAR(255)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO [dbo].[AUDIT_LOG] (finished, query, result) 
    VALUES (GETDATE(), @query, @result);
END
GO

--calling

EXEC [dbo].[SaveAuditLog] @query = 'some query', @result = 'some result';
```